# how to use "cv2.createTrackbar()" function to resize the streaming video frame?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision

I am an enthusiastic learner of opencv and  write down a code  for video streaming with opencv I want to learn the use of cv2.createTrackbar()  to add some interactive functionality. Though, I tried  this function but its not working for me :

For streaming and resizing the frame  i use this code

```
import cv2
import sys
import scipy.misc
import scipy 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(sys.argv[1])

new_size = 0.7  # value range(0,1) can be used for resizing the  frame size 

while(1):

    ret, frame = cap.read() 

    frame = scipy.misc.imresize(frame, new_size)

    cv2.imshow("t",frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
```

Then i have transformed the above code like this to add the track bar functionality to resize the frame.

```
import cv2
import sys
import scipy.misc
import scipy

def nothing(x):
    pass

cv2.createTrackbar('t','frame',0,1,nothing)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(sys.argv[1])


while(1):



    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    j = cv2.getTrackbarPos('t','frame')
    frame = scipy.misc.imresize(frame, j)

     cv2.imshow("t",frame)
     k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
         if k == 27:
             break
```

but this code is not working and ended up with this error given bellow:

```
me@ubuntu:~/Desktop/final_video_soft$ python GUI_STREAM.py p.3gp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GUI_STREAM.py", line 20, in <module>
    frame = scipy.misc.imresize(frame, j)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 365, in imresize
    imnew = im.resize(size, resample=func[interp])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1305, in resize
    im = self.im.resize(size, resample)
TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not float
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it show an error? Does it give an output you were not expecting? Please be more specific.

Comment: Can you print and show the the value of `j`?

Comment: @a-Jays yes i have checked that earlier it was printing "-1" for j.

Comment: It shouldn't be -1. Use `setTrackBarPos()` to set it to one before the loop. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: @a-Jays i already tried this  but same error occurred

Comment: Try `cv2.createTrackbar('t','frame',1,1,nothing)`

Comment: @a-Jays same error :(

Answer (score 2):

Your code will surely fail. There are too many issues indicating you haven't read the document. Even the 1st `new_size` one will **fail for sure**.

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(sys.argv[1])` this is wrong. Because it requires `int` instead of `str`. You have to do `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(int(sys.argv[1]))`

another obvious error is the conflicted window name you give in following code:

```
cv2.createTrackbar('t','frame',0,1,nothing)
cv2.imshow("t",frame)
```

`imshow` used a **window name** 't'. But the 't' is actually the **trackbar name**.

Moreover, if you have read the document you will know the `createTrackbar` will only accept `int` as `val` and `count`. Thus you either have `j = 0` or `j = 1` in your code. The `value` is initial value of the trackbar. Thus in your case it is always 0, which will raise an error in imshow.

The `getTrackbarPos` should be in event triggered callback not in the main loop. If you do it like you posted, it might still run, but it will not respond to every sliding-event. However, it does not cause visible trouble since the video capture loop is quite fast.

After fix all those errors, it will ends up like this:

```
scale = 700
max_scale = 1000



def modified():
scale = 500
_scale = float(scale)/max_scale
cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.createTrackbar('t','frame', scale, max_scale, nothing)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(int(sys.argv[1]))

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    if not ret:
        break
    scale = cv2.getTrackbarPos('t','frame')
    if scale > 1:
        _scale = float(scale)/max_scale
    print "scale = ", _scale
    frame = scipy.misc.imresize(frame, _scale)

    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i am familiar with c++, here is the C++ code, hope it helps.
The code mentioned below adds a contrast adjustment to the live video stream from the camera using createTrackbar function

```
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
    string owin = "Live Feed Original";
    string mwin = "Modified Live stream";
    int trackval = 50;
    Mat oframe;
    Mat inframe;
    VideoCapture video(0);
    if (!video.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "The Camera cannot be accessed" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow(owin);
    moveWindow(owin, 0, 0);
    namedWindow(mwin);
    createTrackbar("Contrast", mwin, &trackval, 100);
    while (1)
    {
        video >> inframe;
        imshow(owin, inframe);
        inframe.convertTo(oframe, -1, trackval / 50.0);
        imshow(mwin, oframe);
        if (waitKey(33) == 27)
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272), because they don't teach the solution.